# Bibliography about non-mathematical applications of logic:

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, formal-theory, formalisation, modelling

I have been recently playing with modal and temporal modal logics in the context of "organisms" (mostly after some study of entelechy in Aristotle and relatedly, some ideas of current biology). I have assisted myself with some ideas of model theory and other logical systems but naturally everything I have managed is quite incoherent and disjoined towards a system of propositions of this kind.

To give myself some clarity I have looked for some similar examples of "applied" logic, but besides a very interesting and recent article about the formalization of Kant's imperatives, the other results are pretty much about fundations of mathematics (not that they do not provide insights).

So I was looking for any help on directions towards any bibliographic information (books/articles or authors) of logical formalization and modelling in non-mathematical objects (or the difficulties therof), any would be appreciated.

Comment: See [IEP Current Applications of Modal Logic](https://www.iep.utm.edu/modal-lo/#H4), [Applications of
Deontic Logic in Computer Science](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9c33/4e2182666c3e504ecea7f48aeb44135ad932.pdf), [Molecular Logic and Computational Synthetic Biology](https://books.google.com/books?id=mIOVDwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s), [Differential dynamic logic
for biological networks](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01568597/document), and [Logic for Systems Biology](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01433682/document).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks a lot! That is exactly the insights I needed, specially about the biological systems, quite on the spot.